# Package dependencies cannot be resolves

Tags: wine, dependencies, playonlinux

When I try to install Wine, PlayonLinux, and some other programs, I get the following message:

**At the terminal**:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine : Depends: wine1.5 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

**At the software center**:

```
Package dependencies cannot be resolved
This error could be caused by required additional software packages which are missing or not installable. Furthermore there could be a conflict between software packages which are not allowed to be installed at the same time.
```

I already tried installing them with "aptitude" and failed.

I am running Ubuntu 12.10

Please help! I've had this problem for a while now and don't know what to do!

Answer (score 3):

First, if you have Synaptic Package Manager installed, I would try the following steps:

1. Open Synaptic
2. Choose **Edit > Fix Broken Packages** from the menu.
3. Choose **Apply Marked Changes** from the **Edit** menu or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>
4. Confirm the summary of changes and click **Apply**

If that doesn't work, or if you don't have Synaptic installed, try:

- `sudo apt-get install -f`

If neither of those work, try these steps in terminal:

1. `sudo apt-get update` to update your package list
2. `sudo apt-get autoclean` to clean up any partial packages
3. `sudo apt-get clean` to clean up the apt cache
4. `sudo apt-get autoremove` will clean up any unneeded dependencies

If, while doing this, you can identify the broken package, this command will very forcefully remove it:

- `sudo dpkg --remove -force --force-remove-reinstreq packagename`

Replace "packagename" with the real name, of course.

If none of those work, I suggest you look at this [Troubleshooting Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PackageManagerTroubleshootingProcedure).

---

Sources:

- [SynapticHowTo - Community Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticHowto#How_to_fix_broken_packages)
- [[SOLVED] How to fix broken packages?](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=947124)

Answer (score 1):

Clean your cache and redownload the packages sudo apt-get clean sudo apt-get autoclean

Try with sudo apt-get install -f , I've been getting these errors too.

Go to ubuntu software center >> Edit >> Software Sources >> Download From >> Select United States After that restart your computer go to software center and type wine and install it

sudo apt-get update to update your package list
sudo apt-get autoclean to clean up any partial packages
sudo apt-get clean to clean up the apt cache
sudo apt-get autoremove will clean up any unneeded dependencies

Open the terminal and copy and paste all this code:

```
sudo apt-get clean &&
sudo apt-get autoclean &&
sudo apt-get autoremove &&
sudo apt-get update &&
sudo apt-get upgrade &&
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa &&
sudo apt-get update &&
sudo apt-get install wine1.5
```

IF THI NO WORK, TRY THIS:
I suggest you to do these: (most of the cases, it works)

Install aptitude with sudo apt-get install aptitude command

Try to install the package you are willing to install with command like

sudo aptitude install 
Aptitude will show you the error and present you a possible (best) solution. You will be asked to choose from 3 options with a message like

Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?]
If you see that your desired package is not listed in the (will be) installed list, simply press n to let aptitude give you the next best solution. After several trial, (if you are lucky) you will see that your desired packages are in installable list and the packages causing the dependency problems will be showing in downgrade list. In this stage Press Y to accept the solution. The packages will be downgraded to satisfy to installation request.

I'm sorry that, I can't give you a demo run of aptitude like this, but you can check this page to see some of it's action.

If, while doing this, you can identify the broken package, this command will very forcefully remove it:

sudo dpkg --remove -force --force-remove-reinstreq packagename
Replace "packagename" with the real name, of course.