# Unable to install wine on 12.10 64-bit

Tags: 12.10, wine, 64-bit

These commands did not work for me as discussed in this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/224824/package-dependencies-cannot-be-resolves):

```
sudo apt-get install wine
[sudo] password for shami: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
```

The following information may help to resolve the situation:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine : Depends: wine1.5 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Package dependencies cannot be resolved                       This error could be caused by required additional software packages which are missing or not installable. Furthermore there could be a conflict between software packages which are not allowed to be installed at the same time.                The following packages have unmet dependencies:

wine:                                                                AND there was an error submitting the transaction

Comment: This error could be caused by required additional software packages which are missing or not installable. Furthermore there could be a conflict between software packages which are not allowed to be installed at the same time.

Comment: you can edit your question to add details, no need to add comments.

Answer (score 0):

Run `sudo apt-get update`, then `sudo apt-get install wine`.